# How to iterate through array and pass each element as parameter to a constructor in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to loop through an array and get each element to pass as parameters to a constructor.
here is my example

```
[user_by_province] => Array
    (
        [label] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
                [3] => d
                [4] => e
                [5] => f
            )

        [count] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 7
                [5] => 1
            )

    )
```

Here is the constructor:

```
$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array('a','2'),
                            array('b','1'),
                            array('c','1'),
                            array('d','1'),
                            array('e','7'),
                            array('f','1')));
```

so how can i do that with php thanks for any help, may we can do that with `array_map` or no? thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested `array_map` with multiple arguments could be a good solution.

```
<?php

$userByProvince = array(
    'label' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
    'count' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'),
);

function combine($arg1, $arg2)
{
    return array($arg1, $arg2);
}

$arguments = array_map('combine', $userByProvince['label'], $userByProvince['count']);

$pc = new C_PhpChartX($arguments);
```

If you are using PHP 5.3 you can even substitute the function with a lambda expression to make the code more compact (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$my_array=array("user_by_province"=>array("label"=>array('a','b','c','d','e','f'),"count"=>array(2,1,1,1,7,1)));
   $new_array=array();
   for($i=0;$i< count($my_array['user_by_province']['label']);$i++){
       $new_values=array();
       array_push($new_values,$my_array['user_by_province']['label'][$i],$my_array['user_by_province']['count'][$i]);
       array_push($new_array,$new_values);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

supposed your given array is ordered and has the same amount of data, i.e. pairs:

loop over your data:

```
$input = array("user_by_province"
         => array("label" => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
                  "count" => array(1, 2, 3)));

$combined = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($input['user_by_province']['label'] && $i < count($input['user_by_province']['count']; $i++)
{
    $combined[] = array($input['user_by_province']['label'][$i], $input['user_by_province']['count'][$i]);
}

$pc = new C_PhpChartX($combined);
```